# Can I get a an already initialized class __init__ arguments, change it, and reinitialize it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, styles, coding-style

What would be the most efficient way if I want to do something like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3,..., arg1000):
       ....

    def reinitilize(arg1):

        # use the already initilized arguments
        # but only use a different input for arg1,
        # and reinitilize the class

        self.already_initilized_args['arg1'] = arg1

        self.__init__ (**self.already_initilized_args)
```

I know I can make a dictionary already in the **init** function or pass a dictionary to the function as kwarg in the first place, but since there are many arguments it would result in a lengthy code in the **init** part. Is there a cleaner more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that saves the init arguments. If you need that, you need to program it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: get a an already initialized class `__init__` arguments, change it, and reinitialize it

There is no need to *reinitialze* anything, you want to assing a new `value` to a `class attribute`.
Which simple can be done with:

```
foo.arg1 = 'new arg1 value'
```

---

To handle a large amount of data, you can use any mutable **container** type, `dict`, `list`, `class object`. Here i show an example using a `dict` as `class attribute self.data`.

- Initialize the object attribute `self.data` by copy the passed `args` using `.update(args)`.
  The parameter `.__init__(..., args)` have to be of type `dict`.

  ```
  class Foo:
      def __init__(self, args):
          self.data = {}
          self.data.update(args)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.data)
  ```

> **Usage**:

- Instantiate the `class Foo` passing your data as `dict`.

  ```
  data = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}

  foo = Foo(data)
  ```
- Show the initalized `values` of the class attribute `self.data`:

  ```
  print(foo)
  >>> {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
  ```
- Change the `value` of your data with `key 'k1'` and show the result.

  ```
  foo.data['k1'] = 'new v1'
  print(foo)
  >>> {'k1': 'new v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
  ```

---

If you prefere to use `object.attribute` notation, you can implement `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`

1. Change in `__init__` the initalisation of `self.data` using `super()...`:

   ```
   def __init__(self, args):
       super().__setattr__('data', {})
       ...
   ```
2. `def __getattr__` return the `value` of the `key` in the `dict self.data`

   ```
   def __getattr__(self, key):
       return self.data.get(key)
   ```
3. `def __setattr__`, change the `value` of `key` in `dict self.data`.

   > **Note**: Updates the `dict self.data` if `key` does not exists.

   ```
   def __setattr__(self, key, value):
       self.args[key] = value
   ```

---

> **Usage**:

```
foo.args['k1'] = 'new v1'
print(foo.k1)
>>> new v1

foo.k2 = 'new v2'
print(foo.k2)
>>> new v2

# Update `foo.data` with `key 'test'`
foo.test = 'test'
print(foo)
>>> {'k1': 'new v1', 'k2': 'new v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'test': 'test'}
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***